# MIDI noise and latency problems

Tags: midi, software, daw, reaper, problems

I have just bought a Roland A49 MIDI controller.
I'm using Reaper as my DAW. I've installed the drivers, and I know that my controller is talking to my DAW, as I am getting a correct red signal through the mixer.

My two main problems are that the latency is massive (2 Seconds), and when I hit the keyboard all I get is horrible white noise/distortion.

I've looked at a few YouTube videos and carefully watched them, but there is nothing on the problems I'm having.

I am running windows 7 and 64 bit software and plugins.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An impression important consideration is which plugins are you using. Depending on your computers CPU & RAM, your synthesizer plugin could easily overload the system and give these results. Can you provide us with the information is just mentioned?

Comment: MIDI does not create noise unless you provide means to do so. Simplified, MIDI data are much like notes on a sheet of paper are to music: no orchestra or band to play, no sound or noise to hear.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that your problem is your audio interface (sound card) driver, not the MIDI controller. I'm not familiar with Reaper but there should be a settings window or something where you pick the driver you want to use.

For low latency you need to pick an ASIO driver. If you don't have one, download ASIO4ALL. This should sort out your latency issue but not necessarily the noise issue which is buffer size related. To fix that, you will need to open the ASIO4ALL (or your sound card's driver) and set the buffer size to a value that is the smallest that does not produce noise. If your project gets heavy, you might get noise again in which case you will have to go back and increase your buffer size a bit further.

Comment: Hey thanks Schizomorph for your insightful answer to my question. I shall look into what you have suggested and let you know the outcome. Appologies for posting this thread in the wrong area. I'm not used to Forums and know they have certain rules and ways of approach. So again sorry for that. Thanks again - Simon.

Comment: Yes, ASIO4ALL is a good start. A buffer length of 128 samples at 44100Hz may be a good start. Reduce it to lower the latency (96, 64…), increase it if the sound cracks too often.